# I have uninstalled Plone, but it's home page keeps showing up at http://localhost:8080/

Tags: tomcat, liferay, uninstallation, plone

I have uninstalled Plone, but it's home page keeps showing up at http://localhost:8080/

That is, when I go to http://localhost:8080/ I see:

Plone

Zope & Plone are now up and running.

```
* Your Plone site has not been added yet: Click here to create a Plone site.
* Use the Zope Management Interface.
* Plone.Org — documentation, add-ons, support, community.
```

I have installed Liferay and need to start working with that. I need to be able to see the Liferay homepage when I got to http://localhost:8080 - it's not a cached page, as I have cleared that several times.

Comment: What platform are you running on? What exactly did you install, and how did you uninstall it?

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds like you've maybe deleted the Plone instance from the Zope database but you still have Zope running.  Plone is a product that runs inside the Zope application platform.  Kill the Zope process and it will no longer bind to port 8080.